# Is there a manual in English for the UYIGAO UA6013L Digital Capacitance Meter?

Tags: identification, multimeter

The UYIGAO UA6013L meter I ordered arrived with an instruction manual in Chinese. I have been unable to obtain a manual in English for this device from the seller or locate one online.

Does anyone know if an English manual for this device exists?

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes ... the manufacturer probably knows if an English manual exists

Comment: I know they meant pF, but I'm amused at the prospect of a meter that claims it can measure petafarads.

Comment: If you need to read the manual, it wasn’t designed very well to understand it or one may lack experience in testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UA6013L appears to be only a [capacitance meter](https://www.uyigao.cn/en/categories/capacitance-meter.html).

> 200pF-20mF Auto Range Tester Capacitor Capacitance Digital Capacitance
> Meter
>
> Specification:
>
> - 1. It is applied with CMOS double-bevel A/D convertor that is automatic in zeroing and polar selection, and makes instruction for
>      beyond measuring range.
> - 2. Wide measuring range, covering 9 measuring sections from 0.1pF to 20,000μF that includes nominal value of any capacitance.
> - 3. Biggest display value: 1999(3 1/2).
> - 4. Reading: 2-3 readings/sec.
> - 5. Zeroing: There is a zeroing knob on the front, easy for operation.
> - 6. Data hold: Put the “HOLD” switch to "ON" and the DH sign will appear on the display.
> - 7. Press the yellow light button , the back light will turn on.
> - 8. Temperature for accurate measuring: 25℃±5℃
> - 9. Temperature range: working temperature: 0℃ to 40℃
> - Storage temperature: -10℃ to 50℃
> - 10. Relative humidity:<80%
> - 11. Power: a 9V laminated battery (NOT including)
> - 12. Dimensions: 143x74x35mm/5.6x2.9x1.4 Inch
> - 13. Material: Plastic

I don't see an English manual for this model but you can easily point a smartphone at it for translation for the few points which might not be clear.

For example, they suggest starting with 200nF for unknown capacitances, and to use the jack rather than the test leads on small value capacitances for better accuracy.